# GKE: right way to mount same PV on multiple pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm having trouble to create a persistent volume that I can use from different pods (1 write, another read).

Tried to use `gcePersistentDisk` directly in the pod spec like in the example on the k8s page (plus `readOnly`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    gcePersistentDisk:
      pdName: my-data-disk
      fsType: ext4
      readOnly: true
```

Then in the second pod spec exactly the same except the `readOnly` ... but got an `NoDiskConflict` error.

Second approach is to use `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: data-standard
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  gcePersistentDisk:
    fsType: ext4
    pdName: data

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: data-standard-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

But now I get an error telling me:

```
MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "kubernetes.io/gce-pd/xxx" (spec.Name: "yyy") pod "6ae34476-6197-11e7-9da5-42010a840186" (UID: "6ae34476-6197-11e7-9da5-42010a840186") with: mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: mount Mounting arguments: /dev/disk/by-id/google-gke-cluster-xxx /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/gke-cluster-xxx [ro] Output: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.
Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"my-deployment". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[data]
```

So what is the correct way of using a GCE disk with multiple pods.

PS: Kubernetes 1.6.6

Answer (score 5):

According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes, GCE Disks do not support ReadWriteMany. I am not sure if this explains the issue but I would advise you to try another compatible Volume type.

Comment: `ReadWriteOnce` with the second approach seems to work but creates a new PV instead of using the one that is already there

Comment: Maybe there is dynamic provision enabled and so it will try to create a new PV, ignoring what there actually is.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ReadWriteMany`, can you use `ReadOnlyMany`?

**Accessmodes:**

***ReadWriteOnce*** – the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node

***ReadOnlyMany*** – the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes

***ReadWriteMany*** – the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

GCE persistent disk do not support `ReadWriteMany`

Here is the list of providers and supported accessmodes:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Comment: I understood `ReadWriteOnce` as "write once" but "read everywhere" ... but I got it wrong :(

Comment: There is an [GKE example here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/stateful-apps) using ReadWriteOnce access mode.

Answer (score 0):

i guess, you should be able to do this by using PV and PVC. let's take an example where you have one pv and PVC. i am not much sure on multi worker-node architecture. i am a minikube user. 
have a check here - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60903

Now you have PV and PVC, both status is bound. now you will use the claim in the pod/deployment resource definition and in pvc name you will use the same claim name. this will attach the volume to both the pods.

```
---
#pv defination:

---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv0
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /path_on_node
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: claim0
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: pv0
--- 
# pod1
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /container_path
              name: vol0
              subPath: sub_path_on_pv(say pod1 so on disk data will be written at /path_on_node/pod1
      volumes:
        - name: vol0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: claim0  
---
# pod2
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /container_path
              name: vol2
              subPath: sub_path_on_pv(say pod2 so on disk data will be written at /path_on_node/pod2
      volumes:
        - name: vol2
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: claim0
```